# What would be a good word to refer to beating an opponent in football (soccer)?

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

I would like to know a good word to refer to the skill of getting past an opponent with the ball during a match. In Brazil we call it *drible*, which is close to *dribble*, but from what I know dribble in english is: to move with the ball. I am looking for a reference word to the ability to beat your opponent; the closest thing i found was *trick*, but that is too generic.

Another problem is that there are names for the different ways to get past an opponent; what I want would be the simplest way, not some elaborate football trick.

Comment: I am working on a Game, and there is a button that refers to the action of trying to get past an opponent, that how generic a word im looking for. Dont really know if it helps. Anyway "Edge out" sounds close to what im going for.

Comment: Surely for a button like that, the action is not "beat" but "attempt to beat".

Comment: That is why i think Edge out would be close to what i am looking for, because to edge out, doesnt mean to beat, at least that is what it sounds like to me. isan't it?

Comment: Now i see that Edge out is more of a term to beat an opponent, i am looking for something more specific like when a player is running towards another and he changes his way fast, to get past the opponent. i was thinking something like "Cut" to refer to the changing the direction, i dont know thats something we use in Brasil, maybe the literal translation just doesnt work.

Comment: *Edge out* is more likely to be used in the context of one team beating another than one player in the team beating another player. A soccer term for the action you describe is "swerve past".

Comment: Swerve might be a good term. That term is more used in the UK or the US, or is it equally known?

Comment: As a British football fan I can tell you for sure it's a common term in British newspaper reports. And here are three extracts from American soccer sites, so it appears to be common there too: "*but Young swerved past her and buried the shot", "she swerved past four defenders before cherry-picking Rosana", "he swerved past two more and rounded the keeper*". "*Swerve past*" is also used for the path the ball takes when it bends past the goalkeeper.

Comment: @BernardGra: Swerve would not work alone; it would have to be swerve past. "Got past" would work also, as long as people wouldn't misunderstand it as "got passed".

Answer (score 2):

You can use *to dribble* like this:

> It was short-lived with Sánchez beating Leno from a tight angle after **dribbling round** the goalkeeper. <sup>[(GUARDIAN)](http://www.guardian.co.uk/football/2012/feb/14/bayer-leverkusen-barcelona-champions-league?INTCMP=SRCH)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The generic term is precisely *beat*, but I can't resist suggesting *nutmeg*, meaning "to put the ball between the legs of an opponent, not only getting past him, but making him look a complete idiot into the bargain".

Comment: I know that nutmeg works, but its too much, i wanted a word for a simple way to beat the opponent. It seems that word doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me how generic a word you are looking for. I can think of: Tom **edged out/ past** Jim, **bested** Jack, **went past** Mike.

From the comments a few things more became clear. I would say **swerve** is a good option, since it means changing the direction to beat a player tactically. However, this precludes beating one in pace, which may not apply for the button you are referring to. Since your idea was in any case the change of direction. But, this is not that generic. Depends on your button mostly!
Will edit back if I can think of more.